# parsing nested xml in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have this XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?><XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData.xsd">
  <TechDataParams>
    <RunNumber>sample</RunNumber>
    <Holder>sample</Holder>
    <ProcessToolName>sample</ProcessToolName>
    <RecipeName>sample</RecipeName>
    <PalletName>sample</PalletName>
    <PalletPosition>sample</PalletPosition>
    <IsControl>sample</IsControl>
    <LoadPosition>sample</LoadPosition>
    <HolderJob>sample</HolderJob>
    <IsSPC>sample</IsSPC>
    <MeasurementType>sample</MeasurementType>
  </TechDataParams>
  <TechDataParams>
    <RunNumber>sample</RunNumber>
    <Holder>sample</Holder>
    <ProcessToolName>sample</ProcessToolName>
    <RecipeName>sample</RecipeName>
    <PalletName>sample</PalletName>
    <PalletPosition>sample</PalletPosition>
    <IsControl>sample</IsControl>
    <LoadPosition>sample</LoadPosition>
    <HolderJob>sample</HolderJob>
    <IsSPC>sample</IsSPC>
    <MeasurementType>XRF</MeasurementType>
  </TechDataParams>
</XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData>
```

And this is my code for parsing the xml:

```python
for data in xml.getElementsByTagName('TechDataParams'):
    #parse xml
    runnum=data.getElementsByTagName('RunNumber')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    hold=data.getElementsByTagName('Holder')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    processtn=data.getElementsByTagName('ProcessToolName'[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
    recipedata=data.getElementsByTagName('RecipeName'[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
    palletna=data.getElementsByTagName('PalletName')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    palletposi=data.getElementsByTagName('PalletPosition')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    control = data.getElementsByTagName('IsControl')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    loadpos=data.getElementsByTagName('LoadPosition')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    holderjob=data.getElementsByTagName('HolderJob')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    spc = data.getElementsByTagName('IsSPC')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    mestype = data.getElementsByTagName('MeasurementType')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

but when i print each node, i am only getting one set of 'TechDataParams', but I want to be able to get all 'TechDataParams' from the XML.

Let me know if my question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't dive into parsing XML with `minidom`, unless you want your hair to be pulled out by yourself.

I would use [`xmltodict` module](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) here. One line and you have a list of dicts with all the data you need:

```
import xmltodict

data = """your xml here"""

data = xmltodict.parse(data)['XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData']['TechDataParams']
for params in data:
    print dict(params)
```

Prints:

```
{u'PalletPosition': u'sample', u'HolderJob': u'sample', u'RunNumber': u'sample', u'ProcessToolName': u'sample', u'RecipeName': u'sample', u'IsControl': u'sample', u'PalletName': u'sample', u'LoadPosition': u'sample', u'MeasurementType': u'sample', u'Holder': u'sample', u'IsSPC': u'sample'}
{u'PalletPosition': u'sample', u'HolderJob': u'sample', u'RunNumber': u'sample', u'ProcessToolName': u'sample', u'RecipeName': u'sample', u'IsControl': u'sample', u'PalletName': u'sample', u'LoadPosition': u'sample', u'MeasurementType': u'XRF', u'Holder': u'sample', u'IsSPC': u'sample'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you. Replace `file_path` with your own.

I replace value of `RunNumber` with `001` and `002`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

from xml.dom import minidom

file_path = 'C:\\temp\\test.xml'

doc = minidom.parse(file_path)
TechDataParams = doc.getElementsByTagName('TechDataParams')
for t in TechDataParams:
    num = t.getElementsByTagName('RunNumber')[0]
    print 'num is ', num.firstChild.data
```

OUTPUT:

```
num is  001
num is  002
```

Comment: thank you! i will also try this method and see what works best!

Answer (score 0):

Also by `lxml.etree` module.

1. Input contain namespace i.e.  `http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData.xsd`
2. Use `xpath` method to find target `TechDataParams` tags.
3. Get children of `TechDataParams` tag and create dictionary which `key` is `tag name` and `value` is `text of tag`.
4. Append to list varaible which is `TechDataParams`.

code:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(content)
TechDataParams_info = []
for  i in root.xpath("//a:XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData/a:TechDataParams", namespaces={"a": 'http://tempuri.org/XMLSchemaPalletLoadTechData.xsd'}):
    temp = dict()
    for j in i.getchildren():
        temp[j.tag.split("}", 1)[-1]] = j.text
    TechDataParams_info.append(temp)

print TechDataParams_info
```

output:

```
[{'PalletPosition': 'sample', 'HolderJob': 'sample', 'RunNumber': 'sample', 'ProcessToolName': 'sample', 'RecipeName': 'sample', 'IsControl': 'sample', 'PalletName': 'sample', 'LoadPosition': 'sample', 'MeasurementType': 'sample', 'Holder': 'sample', 'IsSPC': 'sample'}, {'PalletPosition': 'sample', 'HolderJob': 'sample', 'RunNumber': 'sample', 'ProcessToolName': 'sample', 'RecipeName': 'sample', 'IsControl': 'sample', 'PalletName': 'sample', 'LoadPosition': 'sample', 'MeasurementType': 'XRF', 'Holder': 'sample', 'IsSPC': 'sample'}]
```

Comment: thank you! i will also try this method and see what works best!